# Finding variable in PHP using in_array

Tags: php

I have an array **$datearray**:

Array [0] => Fri 08 Feb 2019 [1] => Sat 09 Feb 2019 [2]

I'm taking todays date to see if it matches anything within the array. I'm putting todays date into a variable **$today**. When I use this variable I get no matches.

I know this will most likely be marked as duplicate but I've been through the other posts and I'm not getting it, any help would be great!

```
$today = date("D d M Y");  
if (in_array($today, $datearray)) {
echo "success";
} else{
echo 'Fail';
}
```

If I add the date in as a string, for example...

```
$today = date("D d M Y");  
if (in_array('Fri 08 Feb 2019', $datearray)) {
echo "success";
} else{
echo 'Fail';
}
```

Then I get the success message, so is this more to do with the data types being different?

**Edited**

This is how I've created the array, sorry I should have added this first...
The times were initially in this format 2019-02-01T17:20:00

```
foreach($xml->Times->EventTime as $Times) {  
$filmdate =$Times->Time;
$filmdatenew = date("D d M Y",strtotime(date($filmdate)));
$datearray[] = $filmdatenew;
```

}

Comment: What do you see with 'echo $today;'?

Comment: What version of PHP?

Comment: @Russ J echo $today gives me Fri 08 Feb 2019

Comment: What about $dateArray, can you post some or all of its contents?

Comment: The dates in $datearray were taken from xml text nodes initially in this format 2019-02-01T17:20:00 I've used $datenew = date("D d M Y",strtotime(date($dateold))) to make them readable for output

Comment: @Grzegorz Adam Kowalski PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26

Answer (score 1):

No. date() returns date string as stated in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). My guess is that the string that date is generating is not the same as you think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running this and getting "success"

```
<?php

$datearray = array();
$datearray[] = "Fri 08 Feb 2019";
$datearray[] = "Sat 09 Feb 2019";
$today = date("D d M Y");
if (in_array($today, $datearray)) {
echo "success";
} else{
echo 'Fail';
}
```

I think maybe you do not have that in the array as you think. What do you get when doing an `echo json_encode($datearray)` ?

Feel free to copy that code on a file and doing `php -f file.php`

Comment: {"0":"2019-02-08T17:20:00"},{"0":"2019-02-09T12:15:00"},{"0":"2019-02-09T20:10:00"},{"0":"2019-02-14T17:20:00"} etc...

Comment: Okay, so you don't have the dates in the format you put before!

Comment: From what I see, you do not have an array with  [0] => Fri 08 Feb 2019 [1] => Sat 09 Feb 2019. You have this  [0] => {[0] : Fri 08 Feb 2019} [1] : { [0] Sat 09 Feb 2019}

So, you have an array in each position of $datearray, I'm editing my answer to help you

Comment: yes that's how I'd converted them for readable output before creating the array.

Answer (score 0):

How are you ?

So, I tried what did you do there (with PHP 7), and this is what happened.

I created my array like this:

```
$datearray = [date("D d M Y", strtotime("2019-02-02")), date("D d M Y", strtotime("2019-02-03"))];
```

So, this way I can compare peaches with peaches and apples with apples :)

Then I used your logic to see what happens

```
$today = date("D d M Y");  
if (in_array($today, $datearray)) {
echo "success";
} else{
echo 'Fail';
}
```

And it works! So, maybe you can show us how did you generate your datearray.

Hope it works!

Comment: The dates in $datearray were taken from xml text nodes initially in this format 2019-02-01T17:20:00 I've used $datenew = date("D d M Y",strtotime(date($dateold))) to make them readable for output, thanks

Comment: @ultrarun and what version of php are you using ?  In short words, is almost the same as I did.

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26

Comment: Can you put a xml example ??

Comment: <Time>2019-02-01T17:20:00</Time> If you look at my edited code you can see my for each is bringing in all of the Time nodes like this example.